# Integration test using AngularJS $http and Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, integration-testing

I have an AngularJS service that calls server via $http like this

```js
function DefineCourseService($http) {
  var service = {
    getCourses: getCourses
  };

  function getCourses(id) {
    return $http({
      url: '/api/Course',
      method: 'GET'
    });
  }
}
```

and the server returns :

```js
[{Code:'123',Title:'Test'}]
```

I want to write an integration test using Jasmine that gets response from server and checks its value. The test file is like:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  define(['angular-mocks', 'defineCourse.service'], function() {
    describe("Course service", function() {
      var courseService, data, deferredResolution, parentScope;

      beforeEach(function() {
        module('modabber.services');

      });

      beforeEach(inject(function($q, $rootScope, DefineCourseService) {
        courseService = DefineCourseService;
        deferredResolution = $q.defer();
        parentScope = $rootScope;
      }));

      it("get courses", function() {
        spyOn(courseService, 'getCourses').and.callThrough();
        deferredResolution.resolve();
        courseService.getCourses().then(function(result) {
          data = result;
        });
        expect(courseService.getCourses).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(data).toBeUndefined();

        parentScope.$digest();
        expect(data).toBeDefined();
        done();
      });
    });
  });
})();
```

and at last my karma.conf.js:

```js
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '../',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],
    files: [
      'karma/test-main.js', {
        pattern: 'WebApiControllers/**/*.js',
        included: false
      }, {
        pattern: 'scripts/vendor/*.js',
        included: false
      }, {
        pattern: 'bower_components/ngMidwayTester/src/ngMidwayTester.js',
        included: false
      }, {
        pattern: 'bower_components/**/*.min.js',
        included: false
      }, {
        pattern: 'scripts/*.js',
        included: false
      }, {
        pattern: 'app/services/*.js',
        included: false
      }, {
        pattern: 'app/directives/*.js',
        included: false
      },

    ],
    exclude: ['scripts/main.js'],
    preprocessors: {    },
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
}
```

but it always fails as "data" is undefined so what's the problem?

Comment: Why aren't you mocking the server response?

Comment: Because I want to check if angular service match with server. for example if server method changed and the angular service forgotten, I should get fail in tests. as integration test value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation

You are setting `data` inside your async callback function, but evaluating it outside.
Imagine your async call takes 3 seconds... This would be its lifecycle:

1. getCourses is called
2. data is undefined and evaluation fails
3. your test finishes
4. ... after 3 seconds... getCourses callback and set it to new value

### Proposal

If you want to test an asyncrhonous call with jasmine as you have in `courseService.getCourses()` you need to notice it to your test using the parameter `done`.

From [jasmine documentation - Asynchronous support](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support):

> This spec will not start until the done function is called in the call
>   to beforeEach above. And this spec will not complete until its done is
>   called.

So basic implementation, as you can see at docu, is:

```
it("takes a long time", function(done) { //done as a parameter
      setTimeout(function() {     
        done();                           //done is resolve to finish your test
      }, 9000);
    });
```

In addition, your expects need to be evaluate after receiving the callback from the async, so introduce them in your `then` callback function.
So, assuming your service injection is correct, you should have something like:

```
it("get courses", function(done) { //Add done as parameter
        // spyOn(courseService, 'getCourses').and.callThrough();Now this spyOn makes no sense.
        deferredResolution.resolve();
        courseService.getCourses().then(function(result) {
          data = result;
          // expect(courseService.getCourses).toHaveBeenCalled(); Not needed
          // expect(data).toBeUndefined();  I assume you are expecting it defined
          // parentScope.$digest(); If you are only evaluating result and it's not change by the $scope, you don't need a $digest.
          expect(data).toBeDefined();
          done();
        }, function(){
           //If your async call fails and done() is never called, 
           // your test will fail with its timeout...
           //... Or you can force a test error
           expect(1).toBe(2);
           done();
        });

      });
```

Comment: You need also to add `done` as parameter and resolve `done()` inside the async callback.

Comment: now it failswith this error: 'expect' was used when there was no current spec, this could be because an asynchronous test timed out

Answer (score 6):

`angular-mock` will not make real ajax calls because it can make unit tests inaccurate. In order to let Angular call the web service and still be able to maintain a good test, I recommend to use [ngMidwayTester](https://github.com/yearofmoo/ngMidwayTester). Combining it with Jasmine's async support (`done()` function), you can perform your test.

```
describe('Course service', function() {
    var tester;
    var courseService;

    beforeEach(function() {
        tester = ngMidwayTester('modabber.services');
        courseService = tester.inject('DefineCourseService');
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        tester.destroy();
        tester = null;
    });

    it('get courses', function(done) {
        courseService.getCourses()
            .then(function(result) {
                expect(result).toBeDefined();
                expect(result.Code).toBe('123');
                done();
            }, function() {
                done.fail('Web service call failed!');
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried to use ngMidWayTester but it's undefined. Is it work properly with RequireJS?

Comment: @mahdi Can you show your `karma.conf.js` or whatever config file you are using?

Comment: @mahdi My bad, I have a typo in my script. `ngMidWayTester` should be `ngMidwayTester` instead, and the test should be `result.Code` instead of `result.code`. Can you try it?